# How to center a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two nested divs. Something like below:-

```
<div id="div1">Some name here
  <div id="div2">DIV2</div>
</div>
```

Suppose the height and width of div1 is 100px. And the height and width of div2 is 50px. How do I make them appear concentric i.e div2 must lie inside div1 equidistant from all sides (using CSS).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Comment: You might want to use percentages for widths in order to make them responsive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If the two divs got fixed dimensions**, you can simply put a margin on the second div. In your case :

```
#div2 {
 margin: 25px;
}
```

**Or, if the divs got variable dimensions**, try :

```
#div1 {
 position: relative;
}
#div2 {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;

transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}
```

OR :

```
#div1 {
text-align: center;

}
#div2 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;

}
```

That's all the way I know to achieve that :)

Comment: This answer should be updated to mention a flexbox way to achieve that.

Comment: Nope: did not work when my div 2 was wider that div1!
I have this situation for a div2 containing a symbol either a line or a dot. I don't want the line to be as big as the rendered makes is (and which I cannot control) and I want the dot to be in the center of div1. (div1 clips div2.)

Comment: div1 clips div2. 
In fact, kind of working, but not if I choose not to clip div2: div2 being bigger does not stay centered in div1!
(Div2 width is auto with the symbol size.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment written by @Praveen but I would do some adjustments:

```
#div1{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#div2{
   margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the automatic left and right margins like the following:

```
<style>
    div#container {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    div#inner {
        border: 1px solid #FF0000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demonstration >**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLuLE/1/)

Comment: It won't center the div vertically.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to use percentages for widths in order to make them responsive.

To center div2 horizontally, insert the following in your css:

```
#div2 {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

To center div2 vertically,

```
#div1 {
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
#div2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It seems your `vertical-align` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: vertical-align doesn't work on block elements, need to set it to inline-block :)

Comment: *`vertical-align`* is a property which works only with [**`inline-level and table-cell elements`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
   #div1 
   {
   border: 1px solid blue; 
   width: 100px;
   height:100px;
   }
   #div2
   {
   margin-left:20px;
   border: 1px dotted red;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   }
   </style>


   <div id="div1">Some name here
   <div id="div2">DIV2</div>
   </div>
```

here is the code to show div in another div with centre css

Answer (score 0):

//If you have height of outer box and inner box both in px or em etc not in % or auto. Here just a logic given using a formula

```
 #div1 {
   display:block;
   height: 500px;
   width:50%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #div2 {      
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    height:60px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: -moz-calc( (500px - 60px) / 2 ) auto; // (height of outer box - height of inner box )/2 
 }

 //may be you can manage height dynamically using js this should work for height in % also  
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var div1_height = $('#div1').height(); 
   var div2_height = $('#div2').height(); 

   var top_margin =  (div1_height-div2_height)/2;
   $('#div2').css('margin',top_margin+'px auto');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

---

#div1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

---

#div1 {
  display: flex;
}
#div2 {
  margin: auto;
}

---

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please explain your answer?